# How can I repair my relationship with management after accidentally getting access to a confidental document?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, people-management, social-nuances

For context, I have been working here a month and requested access to an employee evaluation form I wasn't supposed to have access to.  My skip skip level manager told my manager, and she started asking all these questions about where I got the form, etc. and was mildly freaking out.

This is the message I'm going to send to my skip skip level manager. Any feedback on how you would take it or what I should write instead would be greatly appreciated.

> Hello!
>
> I hope this message finds you in good health and spirits
>
> My name is [my name] and I am new Senior Software Engineer in your organization.  My manager is [my managers name].  I am writing to let you know that I did not realize my coworkers' ratings were available in that "Senior Software Engineers'..." Google Document when I requested access.  I just wanted a few details on how we were being evaluated, so I could focus my efforts towards the most important tasks.  I am new to [company name] and I just want to do a good job.  Again, I had no intention of seeing my coworkers' ratings, I did not realize they were present in the Document
>
> This sprint I am ahead of deadlines, and I already passed the AWS certification weeks ahead of when it was necessary.  Trying to see the evaluations' format was just part of my being proactive and trying to do a good job.  And again, I did not realize my coworkers' ratings were in that document.  I was just trying to do a good job
>
> Sincerely, and thank you for your time, [my name]
>
> P.S.  I hope you have a great weekend!  [company name] is a great place to work and I am grateful for the opportunity to contribute to [company name]'s codebase and products

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150292/discussion-on-question-by-spolsky-fan-how-can-i-repair-my-relationship-with-mana); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Can you clarify: Were you actually *granted* access, and if so, did you *open* the document?  The title implies you opened the document, but the question itself implies you never got access.

Answer (score 91):

Good, but too long (IMO). It's typically better to keep this type of thing short and to the point.

Tell them that

1. You accessed a document to learn about performance evaluation
2. You realized that this document contained confidential information. At this point you did XXX (insert whatever you did).
3. You did not intend to access information, you apologize for it and you will make sure it doesn't happen again. Add any specific action if there are any.
4. You appreciate any feedback or suggestions they might have.

Keep it factual and keep the decoration to a minimum. Don't talk about your performance since it's irrelevant to this incident. You don't need to beat yourself up too badly: if you had access to a document that you shouldn't have had access to, someone else screwed up and chances are your manager(s) know that.

Comment: Right. The emphasis here is "oops,  you might want to improve security on that document so someone else doesn't make the same mistake." Your own history and performance is completely irrelevant to that message.

Comment: "I accessed the document to learn how to cheat the system, accidentally saw everyone's evaluations, when I realized, I copied them for future use and hoped nobody would notice. I didn't intend to access the information because I didn't know I could. It won't happen again if you improve security. I appreciate your feedback, if any, though with my newly gained knowledge I probably won't need it." -- Am I doing this right?

Comment: Regarding item 3: should the OP be apologizing for someone else giving them information the OP should not have been given?

Comment: I would also recommend explicitly noting that none of the information will be shared with anyone.  Also, don't divulge any of the information.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this really depends on company culture. If you work in a trusting environment, many may operate under the assumption "if you request access, you will have a good reason for it" So by requesting access the OP implied having a valid reason for needing access to that document. (A request for technical access can include the passage "I hereby acknowledge that access to this document is strictly necessary to perform my obligations and I will only use it to perform these obligations.")

Comment: @Falco You're describing a culture that doesn't care about security. *Trust but verify* is the first rule of security. The person who allowed this culture to exist is responsible for the consequences.

Comment: @Falco A person without access to that document is likely not to know everything that's in it. So even in a trusting environment, it's reasonable and prudent to check that a person's access request is appropriate. They may honestly think they should have access to it, when in fact they shouldn't, because they misunderstand what's in it. In fact, that seems to be OP's situation exactly. The OP didn't do anything wrong (unless they actively manipulated someone into believing they should have access to it, which doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: @yshavit I would argue the OP didn't do much wrong - but he could probably have asked what is in the document before requesting access to it. It currently sounds like the OP just saw the name of the document and thought "That sounds interesting" and requested access. And depending on company culture this may be the wrong way to do things.

Comment: @employee-X I'm with you on trust-but-verify. But I know many instances in which the timely access to data is a higher priority, so verification usually comes in a revision process after the fact. In this case management is ready to take the risk of someone accessing the wrong data - the risk is mitigated by an environment like I described and of course by verification after the fact and prosecution of illegitimatly accessing data.

Answer (score 69):

If your skip skip level manager hasn't contacted you directly, do not send them any messages.

There's a reason that they spoke to your manager - delegation. They've passed this on to your manager, so that's who you should be talking with.

The right thing to do here is move on. Any further engagement on the topic can only serve to exacerbate things.

If it keeps getting brought up, just point out that the fact that you got access to a document is not remotely your doing. You asked, but it was someone else who granted and the mistake is theirs.

Comment: +100, If your skip  or skip-skip manager wants something directly from you, they will definitely let you know.  Otherwise don't bother them

Answer (score 55):

You don't mention your location but from my UK perspective, your message is terribly [brown nosing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brown-nosing). Sure, you got access to a doc you shouldn't have seen but you don't need to make such a fuss about it. Just apologise and move on - as a senior manager, I don't actually care about your sprint tasks very much at all.

Your bigger problem may be repairing your relationship with your direct manager and your team.

Comment: Why would OP need to apologize for someone else granting OP access to a document they should not have been given access to? I don't see why this would be OP's fault.

Comment: @Neinstein going around requesting access to random documents is not really the right way to do things. If the OP wanted to know the criteria on which they would be evaluated, they should have just asked their manager in the first place. Yes, access shouldn't have been granted, so it's not entirely (or maybe even mostly) the OP's fault but there were better ways to go about this which wouldn't have caused the problem.

Comment: If the evaluation is done in a centralized way, managed by HR, policies, and forms, I don't see why it would be inappropriate to ask HR directly for your results instead of the direct manager. I'd even say it's more appropriate. Granted, we don't know who OP asked, but it's safe to assume that they have been involved in the evaluation process, so they have been a reasonable contact. OP didn't request a random document but their own evaluation sheet. Not OP's fault they also (?) got someone else's.

Comment: @Neinstein _"I don't see why this would be OP's fault."_ I don't think it is. Manager (or whoever granted access) should just have said "nah ah .... can't do. But eval criteria are x, y and z." - _But_ not simply asking manager for exactly that information but access to a document, where OP _guessed_ to find it is what _I_ would be suspicious about if I were their coworker.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: "going around requesting access to random documents is not really the right way to do things" - your experience may differ here, but I for one am already swamped by requests from my reports and others. I am grateful for anyone who takes the little bit of effort of looking for the right documents on the company-wide fileshares themselves rather than waiting for me to spoon-feed every bit of information to them. But, maybe more importantly, *is* it not the right way? We are looking at A) a free-form request that will get buried in someone's mailbox or chat history (if at all ...

Comment: ... it was originally issued in writing) versus B) a structured request of the kind that can be systematically and automatically logged somewhere ("User X requested access to path Y at timestamp Z and provided rationale ABC."). I'm not saying the OP's company already does such a logging, but going to a file and triggering some process to request access is a good start.

Answer (score 29):

Too long and too much "fluff". Here's what I would suggest:

> [Skip Level Manager Name or Preferred Salutation], My name is [my
> name]. I'm a new Senior Software Engineer. My manager is [my managers
> name]. I wanted to clarify that when I requested access to the "Senior
> Software Engineers" document I didn't realize that it contained
> information that I should not have been privy to. My apologies for any
> inconvenience this may have caused.

Comment: While factually correct, showing a little bit of remorse would help imho.

Comment: Remorse for what exactly. It does not seem like OP deliberately tried to access a document they shouldn't. When requesting google doc access, you can't really see what the document has in it, do you?

Comment: Remorse (or perhaps regret) for having caused others trouble, even though there was no intention to do so.

Comment: **My apologies for any inconvenience this may have caused.** - Seems like a perfectly sufficient and appropriate expression of "remorse" in this scenario.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato +1 to your comment. I would also add - not into the letter or even say it loud, obviously - that if the document is private, the keepers should not give access to whoever. And if you are new to a company and try to build a picture of processes you occasionally try to access documents not supposed to be accessed by you. This is why companies have access restrictions.I once joined a new company and asked access to company Dynamics as some stored procedures in my product read from it. I just got the request declined and was explained why. I just had no idea what Dynamics were :)

Comment: If I step on your foot I show remorse even if I'm convinced you moved it into my way and it's not my fault. That type of remorse.

Answer (score 14):

> requested access to an employee evaluation form

Umm, so who the heck approved your access?

Somebody f*cked up; it wasn't you unless you've been caught social-engineering something devious.

---

> she started asking all these questions about where I got the form, etc.

Hopefully they're investigating where their procedures colossally fell apart and want to remediate the procedure.

---

> and mildly freaking out

Stahp, you're hurting yourself in confusion.

Profusely apologizing makes you look incompetent.

Comment: "Profusely apologizing makes you look incompetent.": no incompetent at OP’s job, but incompetent at understanding where/who’s at fault here: the person that granted access to the document.

Comment: Sounds like somebody in the list of "approvers" has just received an email with an approve button and automatically clicked it. We've had a couple of incidents like this (with pull requests being approved by someone who shouldn't be in the approvers group but was for some reason), the answer is indeed to look at the controls here. OP has some responsibility (if they wanted to find out the requirements for Senior Software Engineer or whatever, they should have checked with their boss whether that was the right document) but so does the approver.

Answer (score 14):

I see no reason for you to "apologise" for this.

You *requested* access to a document, which you believed you had a justifiable reason to look at.
Anyone might reasonably expect an "Evaluation" Form to be a *blank template*, not a copy of the last evaluation that somebody carried out.

**Someone else** *approved* your access to the document, or simply gave you the wrong one.
That's on them, not you.

You *received* the [wrong] document, realised this and are [now] looking to take positive action.
One of your Managers *also* realised this and started "freaking out".  That's poor Management style and suggestive of a deeper-rooted "laxness" in security.

All that said, this should already be out of your hands.
The document contained **Personal** data about other employees.  Under GDPR, this constitutes a **Reportable Data Breach** and your Compliance team should be *all over* this.
If they're not, they're the *next* people you need to speak with.

Comment: The best answer so far, that’s straight to the point : someone ELSE is at fault, and "your Compliance team should be all over this. If they're not, they're the next people you need to speak with"

Comment: +1 That OP was even able to ask for access (i.e. see the file name in a public folder) points at some dire mismanagement.

Answer (score 9):

Do not send anything in writing to the higher-ups. Maybe it is already calming down. If not, it'll go through your manager.
However, I can understand you want to express your apology, but it's better to interact only with your manager. So you could modify your text for her/him. As others have pointed out, you should shorten your message. I'm taking your words but recommend to completely remove the striked through parts:

> Hello [my managers name] and
> To whom it may concern,
>
> I hope this message finds you in good health and spirits. Please feel free to forward my explanation to anyone with questions about the situation.
>
> <strike>My name is [my name] and I am new Senior Software Engineer in your
> organization. My manager is [my managers name].</strike> I am writing to let
> you know that I did not realize my coworkers' ratings were available
> in that "Senior Software Engineers'..." Google Document when I
> requested access. I just wanted a few details on how we were being
> evaluated *and I simply assumed the document to only contain public information about the evaluation criteria.* <strike>so I could focus my efforts towards the most important
> tasks. I am new to [company name] and I just want to do a good job.
> Again, I had no intention of seeing my coworkers' ratings, I did not
> realize they were present in the Document</strike>
> *I have not shared this document with anyone [and my access has already been revoked].*
>
> <strike>This sprint I am ahead of deadlines, and I already passed the AWS
> certification weeks ahead of when it was necessary. Trying to see the
> evaluations' format was just part of my being proactive and trying to
> do a good job. And again, I did not realize my coworkers' ratings were
> in that document. I was just trying to do a good job</strike>
>
> I am sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused.
>
> Sincerely, and thank you for your time, [my name]
>
> <strike>P.S. I hope you have a great weekend! [company name] is a great place
> to work and I am grateful for the opportunity to contribute to
> [company name]'s codebase and products</strike>

The statement that your access has been revoked is hopefully true, otherwise request that and mention the revocation request instead!

Comment: "Do not send anything in writing..." Anything you send in writing to *any* employee is available to the CEO. For digital documents, all it takes is a conference call to the heads of legal, HR and IT. That said, it would be good for the OP to keep a written record of what happened, in case they have a reason to talk to a lawyer later.

Comment: This is good, but this is way too formal. Remove the formal salutations. And instead of saying: "I have not shared this document with anyone", just say: "I have not shared this document with anyone and I stopped reading as soon as I saw that it contained information that wasn't meant for me."